# Implement a bar over ViewController that does not animate (like tab bar)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have two main ViewControllers in my project. I would like to add in both ViewControllers a bottom bar that has buttons (different for each ViewController) that take user to a respective subViewController, just like a Tab Bar. But the first ViewController  must have a button inside its View that takes the user to the other main ViewController without animate the bar during the transition among ViewControllers. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could add the view as a subview of `UIWindow`, and not your respective view controller. Alternatively, why not subclass `UITabBar`?